# How to display the lastmessage sent when user is not inside the chat?

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I currently have 2 screens an all messages screen which includes all the chats i participated in and a chat screen which is the actual chat itself.

In my chat screen i successfully implemented sockets, so when both users are on the chat screen at the same time messages are getting exchanged live.

My problem:

If user 1 is on the allmessages screen and user 2 is inside the chat. And user 2 sends user 1 a message, user 1's screen does not automatically update with the last message for the conversation the message was sent to, I need to either scroll to refresh or navigate from one page to the other in order for it to appear.

I got suggested to use socket on the allmessages screen to listen to any event change.

In my database I have a conversations table and a messages table. The conversation table has the following fields: id, user1, user2, postId, lastMessage. The messages table has the following fields:id, senderID, receiverID, conversationId, message.

CLIENT

Chatscreen.js

```
useEffect(() => {
const newsocket =io.connect("IP:PORT")
setMessages(message.Messages)

newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`)
setSocket(newsocket)
newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);
 });

newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
console.log("this is the chat messages:", msg);
setMessages(messages => messages.concat(msg))
});

return(()=>newsocket.close());

}, []);

const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
console.log("sent")
const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)
socket.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,ConversationId });
setText("")
messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
};
```

allmessagesScreen.js

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const[page,setPage]=useState(0);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);

if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

setError(false);

setPosts(response.data)
};

useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
loadPosts();
});
return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);

return(

<FlatList
    data={posts}
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
      <MessagesList
      title={item.Post.title}
        subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT,{message:item,index})}
      />
    )}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    onRefresh={() => {
      loadPosts()
    }}
  />
```

SERVER

```
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
console.log('User '+socket.id+' connected')

socket.on('subscribe', (room)=> {
console.log('joining room', room);
socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data)
console.log('sending room post',data.ConversationId)
io.sockets.in(data.ConversationId).emit('send_message', { message: 
data.message, receiverId: 
data.to,senderId:data.from,conversationId:data.ConversationId });
})
})
```

I gave the following a try, my console logs are getting printed but the functionality still doesn't work.

CLIENT

Chatscreen.js

```
useEffect(() => {
const newsocket =io.connect("IP:PORT")
setMessages(message.Messages)

newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`)
setSocket(newsocket)
newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);
 });

newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
console.log("this is the chat messages:", msg);
setMessages(messages => messages.concat(msg))
});

return(()=>newsocket.close());

}, []);

const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
console.log("sent")
const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)
socket.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,ConversationId });
setText("")
messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
};
```

allmessagesScreen.js

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const[page,setPage]=useState(0);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);

if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

setError(false);

setPosts(response.data)
};

  useEffect(() => {
  const newsocket =io.connect("http://ip:port")
  loadPosts()

   newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log(`waiting for user: ${user.id} to join a conversation`) //this gets printed 
    setSocket(newsocket)
    newsocket.emit('waiting', user.id);
   });

 newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
  console.log("this is the last message:", msg); //this doesnt get printed 
});
   }, []);

return(

<FlatList
    data={posts}
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
      <MessagesList
      title={item.Post.title}
        subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT,{message:item,index})}
      />
    )}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    onRefresh={() => {
      loadPosts()
    }}
  />
```

SERVER

```
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
console.log('User '+socket.id+' connected')//this gets printed 

socket.on('subscribe', (room)=> {
console.log('joining room', room);//this gets printed 
socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('message', (data) => {

console.log(data) //this gets printed 
console.log('sending room post',data.ConversationId) //this gets printed 
io.sockets.in(data.ConversationId).emit('send_message', { message: 
data.message, receiverId: 
data.to,senderId:data.from,conversationId:data.ConversationId }); 
})

socket.on('waiting', (user)=> {
console.log('user', user, 'is waiting.');//this gets printed 
});

})
```

Comment: Does `console.log('User '+socket.id+' connected')` got triggered c?

Comment: @AvivLo On Server side yes, when i reload my app and go to the allmessages screen i get `User S1CTDD6euE593ZYaAAB1 connected`
`user 53 is waiting.`  and on the client side i get `waiting for user: 53 to join a conversation`

Comment: Are you familiar with event emitter? every `emit` on the backend should have a corresponding `on` on the client, vice versa.

Comment: @AvivLo Hi, sorry to bother you but i have updated the question if you can please have a look

Comment: @kd12345 Instead of creating the connection in the component, I recommend using redux-sagas to manage a background websocket connection.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for getting back to me. Is there any possible way to achieve this without redux, i have never used it before. Also, what i think i should do is and a listener to the send_message event in allmessagesScreen (same as in chat screen) and when a message is sent in the chatscreen i add it to the array of messages in the allmessagesscreen which will cause re-rendering automatically.

Comment: @kd12345 It doesn't make sense to create a connection everytime a user enters a specific chat page. Can you create the connection at a higher level component that contains both the chat list and chat pages? The connection is then maintained while the app is open, and incoming connection messages should indicate things like type ("newMessage") and accompanying data (chatId, message)

Comment: @Aaron thank you for getting back to me again. so basically, i create the connection at the allConversations Screen instead of in both screens and just emit the send_message event inside the chat screen then listen to it on the allConversations Screen? or do you mean i create the connection on my home screen instead of in allConversations Screen?

Comment: @kd12345 You can create the connection on any component that does not get unmounted while navigating to different pages of your app (chat page, settings page, etc.), so your connection does not terminate. What do you use to persist the app state? Redux and redux-sagas is popular and easy to use. I still recommend it.

Comment: @Aaron hi, I currently created my connection on a separate file called socket.js and imported it inside my allmessages screen. my problem now is that i cant pass the newsocket variable from the allmessages screen to the chat screen without using redux.

Comment: Hi @kd12345, you'll either have to create the individual chat components as children of the allMessages screen, record the child refs in the parent, and have the parent invoke the child methods to update them. Any reason you're avoiding a state management tool like redux?

Comment: @Aaron i will give that a try, thank you. When i started my programming journey i got recommend if i am not maintaining the state throughout the entire application then there is no point in using redux even though it is makes coding easier. But i will definitely as soon as i am done with this project. what do you mean by this `create the individual chat components as children of the allMessages screen` ?

Comment: @Aaron i think this is what i currently have. Allmessages is my parent component and chatScreen is my child component. The connection is being initialized on my parent component and hence the child component needs to know about this same connection as well not create a new one.

Comment: What you're doing already justifies state management (e.g. with redux). When the connection receives the message, save it to state. Then, when the child component loads, look into the state for existing/new messages.

Comment: @kd12345 You should really do it the right way. Your approach is getting messier and messier, so this will be my final reply entertaining that approach. Basically all your children would need to be mounted and have their refs recorded by the parent. Your children also need a method like `recordNewMessage` that the parent will call whenever the connection receives a new message for that child. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got same problem yesterday. But now it has been fixed. This one should works

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import socket from 'socket.io-client'

const Chatbox = () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const socketClientRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = socket("http://localhost:3002");
    client.on("connect", () => {
      console.log('connected')
    })
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log('diconnected')
    });
    client.on("chat", message => {
      setChats(prevChats => [...prevChats, message])
      // INSTEAD OF:
      // setChats([...chats, message])
    });
    socketClientRef.current = client
    return () => {
      client.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }, [])

  const handleSend = async () => {
    socketClientRef.current.emit('chat', {
      room: `event-${eventId}`,
      message
    })
    setMessage('')
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Messages</h1>
        {chats.map(chat => (
          <div>{chat}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <input value={message} onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. Is this the chat screen itself where users exact messages? if yes, this is working for me, my problem is eg. if user1 is inside the chat and  user2 is on the screen which has all the chats, the last message sent does not update automatically to user2 if user 1 sends a message. Do you get my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> : if user 1 is on the allmessages screen and user 2 is inside the chat. And user 2 sends user 1 a message, user 1's screen does not automatically update with the last message for the conversation the message was sent to

When `user2` sends a message, emit an event with `socketid` of `user1`. The message will be received by `user1` with help the `on` event. It doesn't matter on which page `user1` will be as long as `user1` is listening to the event.

Just make sure to send the metadata of the messages so that you will be able to differentiate and handle the messages on client side.

Comment: if both users are inside the chat my code is working properly and messages get rendered live. my problem is if user2 is inside the chat and user1 is on the screen with all the chats and user2 sends user1 a message, the screen with all the chats doesnt update automatically

Comment: does event fire when the user is on all chat screen?

Comment: the connection event fires but the send_message event inside the allmessages screen no

Comment: Hey Abhishek, can you please help me out really stuck and my boss whats me to get this fixed today.

Comment: Sure, just share me your repo link. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: thank you alot, can you create a discussion so i can explain my problem in details?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where to start. So can you do it?